# Does it fill from the top or bottom

Tags: r, matlab, translation

I am trying to translate this MatLab code into R.

```
% ensure existing positions are carried forward
unless there is an exit signal positions=
fillMissingData(positions);
```

Here is the information I have about the fillMissingData function:

```
function [filledPrices]=fillMissingData(prices)
% [filledPrices]=fillMissingData(prices) fill data in a 2-dim array with NaN's with the
% previous value.

filledPrices=prices;
for t=2:size(filledPrices, 1)
missData=~isfinite(filledPrices(t, :));
filledPrices(t, missData)=filledPrices(t-1, missData);
end
```

The object the function is performed on is "positions" a 2 column matrix with data that looks like this:

```
1 -1
1 -1
NaN NaN
NaN NaN
0 0
NaN NaN
1 -1
```

My solutions is just to use the r code:

```
positions <- na.locf(positions, fromLast=FALSE)
```

to fill with the previous value, but I am not sure if that is what the MatLab functions does, especially because I am told to "carry 0's forward"

Please help!

Comment: For those of us that don't know Matlab, can you tell us what it is you are trying to do?

Comment: You could use octave to execute the m-code and compare the results of both.

Comment: @RichardScriven I'll provide an explanation.  I'll leave it to you `R` folks to write an answer.  Given a 2D matrix, starting from the second row down to the end, the job is to find those entries in that row that are `NaN`. (I personally would have used `isnan`).  For those entries that are `NaN`, you copy those values from the **previous** row over from those column locations that were `NaN` into the corresponding locations in the current row.  This looks like some sort of data imputing.

Comment: @claushojmark - If the first two rows consisted of `NaN` elements where the same column contains those `NaN` entries, the data would not be properly imputed.  How do you handle the case where the first row has `NaN` elements?

Comment: So the question you're asking is, what exactly does the matlab code do?

Comment: @rayryeng - Well actually that is a second problem of mine. If the first row contains NaN element, they should be 0, but how would I make such a test?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A naive/word-to-word translation to R would be

```
fillMissingData <- function(prices){
  filledPrices=prices
  for (t in 2:nrow(filledPrices)){
    missData=is.na(filledPrices[t, ])
    filledPrices[t, missData]=filledPrices[t-1, missData]
  }
  filledPrices
}
```

And it does exactly what `na.locf(positions, fromLast=FALSE)` does.

```
positions <- matrix(c(1, -1, 1, -1, NA, NA,NA, NA,0, 0,NA, NA, 1, -1), ncol=2, byrow=TRUE)
fillMissingData(positions) 

#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,]    1   -1
#[2,]    1   -1
#[3,]    1   -1
#[4,]    1   -1
#[5,]    0    0
#[6,]    0    0
#[7,]    1   -1
```