# replace zero values with previous non-zero values

Tags: matlab, indexing, vectorization

I need a fast way in Matlab to do something like this (I am dealing with huge vectors, so a normal loop takes forever!):

from a vector like

```
[0 0 2 3 0 0 0 5 0 0 7 0]
```

I need to get this:

```
[NaN NaN 2 3 3 3 3 5 5 5 7 7]
```

Basically, each zero value is replaced with the value of the previous non-zero one. The first are `NaN` because there is no previous non-zero element
in the vector.

Comment: Closest or previous, your example output shows that you are replacing zeros with the previous non-zero value, not the closest...

Comment: yes, sorry.. you are right.. I want the previous one. I will modify the question..

Comment: possibly interesting alternative code:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27950664/does-it-fill-from-the-top-or-bottom

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this, not sure about speed though. Got to run so explanation will have to come later if you need it:

```
interp1(1:nnz(A), A(A ~= 0), cumsum(A ~= 0), 'NearestNeighbor')
```

Comment: yes, that works perfectly and it is fast enough! Thanks!

Comment: Matlab2012 lists  `nearest` -- presumably that's the same method as `NearestNeighbor` ?

Comment: @CarlWitthoft the [docs (2015a)](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/interp1.html#inputarg_method) say `'nearest'` as well, my mistake (although it seems to work fine anyway)

Answer (score 2):

Try this (it uses the [`cummax`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cummax.html) function, introduced in R2014b):

```
i1 = x==0;
i2 = cummax((1:numel(x)).*~i1);
x(i1&i2) = x(i2(i3));
x(~i2) = NaN;
```

Comment: I have an older version of Matlab.. I can't try it.. but thanks!

Comment: @user1835630 if you can find the source code for cummax (or roll your own),  you can implement it in any Matlab version.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft Unfortunately, it doesn't have any source code, because it's a builtin function. The good thing about that is that it's very fast

Comment: urrgh.  That's why I like open source :-(

Answer (score 0):

Just for reference, here are some similar/identical functions from exchange central and/or  SO columns.

[nearestpoint](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/8939-nearestpoint--sep-2012-) ,

try `knnimpute` function.

Or best of all, a function designed to do exactly your task:

[repnan](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/48324-repnan/content/repnan/html/repnan_documentation.html)  (obviously, first replace your zero values with `NaN`)

Answer (score -2):

I had a similar problem once, and decided that the most effective way to deal with it is to write a `mex` file.  The `c++` loop is extremely trivial. After you'l figure out how to work with `mex` interface, it will be very easy.

Comment: I strongly disagree that the best way to deal with deficiencies in a language is to learn two other languages.  The whole point of Matlab, Mathematica, R,  Julia, etc.  is **not** tohave to deal with low-level languages like `c` or `c++` .

Comment: @CarlWitthoft thanks for your opinion. When you are interested in raw speed, there is a limit to Matlab abilities. Mex is a great way to deal with it (That is why it exist). Take a look at MathWorks - you will see tons of mex files, exactly for this reason.

Comment: No argument there, but a better response (from Mathworks) would be to provide builtin functions to compile/optimize the Matlab code itself, as is done, e.g.  with  `parfor`  function to simplify multicore operation.